# Haskell repa : inner product result of two array is wrong

Tags: haskell, repa

```
import Data.Array.Repa
import Data.Vector.Unboxed hiding(zipWith)
import Prelude hiding(zipWith,replicate)

dotp :: Array U DIM1 Float -> Array U DIM1 Float -> IO Float
dotp x y =  sumAllP $ zipWith (*) x y

x = fromUnboxed (Z:.20000000) $ replicate 20000000 1 
y = fromUnboxed (Z:.20000000) $ replicate 20000000 1

main = (dotp x y) >>= print
```

Compiled with `ghc -O2 -threaded test.hs`

However, when I execute the executable with `./test +RTS -N1`

the result is `1.6777216e7`

while `./test +RTS -N2` or with more cores,

the result is correct : `2.0e7`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Welome to underflow. Chapter 4 of Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms: Second Edition By Nicholas J. Higham covers floating point summation in some detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `Float` instead of `Double`. `Float` doesn't have enough significant digits (~7) for your use case:

```
λ> (1.6777216e7 :: Float) + 1
1.6777216e7
```

Switch to `Double`. If all your values are integral, consider `Int` (or `Intxx` from [`Data.Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Int.html)) or `Word` (from [`Data.Word`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Word.html)).

#### See also:

- [WP: Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: A word of caution to the OP: you can still experience this sort of problem with Double.